# Bootstrap JS works, but not tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've confirmed that my bootstrap.js works by invoking a dropdown, and also a modal popup. Both of them work, but when I try to get tooltip to work it fails. As far as I understand from the documentation [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) you merely have to put this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Default tooltip">you probably</a>
```

However, no tooltip appears at all. Yet, the dropdown that I invoke with the same API as below works:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
        Dropdown
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you downloaded a customized version of BStrap or the full? And also, did you implemented you JS code?

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Web it was the "$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()" part that I didn't implement. Thanks to Bojangles' answer below it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the tooltips incorrectly. You only need to provide the `title` attribute - the tooltip plugin sets the `data-original-title` itself.

Also, from the documentation:

> For performance reasons, the tooltip and popover data-apis are opt in, meaning **you must initialize them yourself.**

So, do something like:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

as a catch-all. You most likely want to select fewer elements to keep decent performance, though.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thanks a lot! Missed that in the docs, I should learn to read I guess :)